# Como usar variavel $wpdb no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

tenho esse código num arquivo php dentro da instalação do wordpress, nao funciona nao sei o que esta errado.

```
global $wpdb;

$tableName = "wp_posts";

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tableName");

foreach ($result as $row) {

echo '<p>' .$row->coluna_teste. '</p>';
```

Comment: Está com exatamente esses parametros? porque realmente tudo está errado desse jeito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) retorna uma lista de objetos por padrão, em que cada propriedade é uma coluna. A tabela `wp_posts` não tem uma coluna `coluna_teste`, por isso o erro.

O codigo abaixo está correto e vai trazer os títulos:

```
global $wpdb;

// Para tabelas padrãdo do WP Use $wpdb->nomedatabela para buscar o nome 
// já com o prefixo, que pode não ser o mesmo em todos os ambientes
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} LIMIT 10" );

foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<p>' . $row->post_title . '</p>';
}
```

[Documentação completa da classe `$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)

PS: O resultado dessa consulta é o mesmo de `get_posts()`. Usar a função é preferível.